# sqlpackage.exe to ignore a specific schema in DevOps Release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, dacpac, sqlpackage

I want to ignore changes to a specific schema in the release pipeline in DevOps. I am trying to find the Sqlpackage.exe command for it. I checked the document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15 but couldn't find it. I am using DACPAC Deployment as shown below:

[image]

Any help on this please?

Answer (score 5):

SqlPackage can not ignore schemas. However, you can try an extension for SqlPackage: https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer

It adds additional options for SqlPackage:

```
/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter=IgnoreSchema(BLAH)"
```

Comment: Do you know how we can add this .dll to be used in the agent job of the release pipline?

Comment: @Sindu_ Try to add the dll to the sqlpackage. exe directory: https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer/releases/tag/1.4.4.1

Comment: Confirming this works with self hosted azure dacpac deployments via the `Additional Arguments` section. Just make sure your regex is correct. Somehow it doesn't like some generic stuff so try to make the regex condition look like the ones provided on the documentation